# Airplane mode goes off only after suspend - Ubuntu 20.04 HP rtl8723be

Tags: drivers, suspend, hp, 20.04, airplane-mode

This problem is reverse of mostly discussed issue. I had window 10 in my system. Airplane hardware switch(F12) and wifi was working normally. Then I replace OS with latest **Ubuntu 20.04**

I followed https://github.com/lwfinger/rtlwifi_new and installed the appropriate driver version **rtl8723be**.

Still I was not able to turn off airplane mode even after setting `ant_sel`. I tried swapping `fn` key behavour from BIOS as well (fn +12 now for airplane mode).

It still shows `hard blocked`. Killing has no effect.

> Accidently I observed that whenever I suspend the system and login again,
>   airplane symbol automatically goes off and wifi starts working. I prefer to do it each time when I start the laptop. First I suspend it at login screen itself and then
>   login to get wifi working. Hardware switch also starts working after this.

PC Info:
Serial No.:CND6106GVP
Model: HP Notebook - 15-af006ax (ENERGY STAR)
Wifi Card: **rtl8723be**

Comment: The bold text in the bloc quote almost looks like you're shouting... :)

Comment: @ThunderBird I heard u :)

Comment: great! It now looks better.